# Replacing non-alphanumeric characters on specific lines in multiple files

Tags: bash

I have several (JSON) files in a directory. I am wanting to scan all files for the line with the `audio` property (first string in quotes) and replace all non-alphanumeric characters in the associated value (second string with quotes) with an underscore. For example, if the line is:

```
"audio": "Sub Dir/my file` nāme.mp3"
```

I would like to replace it with:

```
"audio": "Sub_Dir/my_file__n_me.mp3"
```

What can I do to replace these lines in multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -i".bak" -pe 's/("audio":\s"*)(.+?)"/
    $x = $1;
    ($y = $2) =~ s#[^A-Za-z0-9_\/\.]#_#g;
    $x . $y . "\""/e' *.json
```

- The `e` option to the `s/../../` function enables the substitution
  to be the result of evaluation of `perl` expression.
- The substition `s#[^A-Za-z0-9_\/\.]#_#g` is performed on the
  second string with quotes and replaces characters other
  than ascii alphabets, digits, underscores, slashes, dots with underscores.
- Original files are saved with the suffix `.bak`.